# Url rewriting broke my include

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i have a problem with my url rewriting let me show you, my code is:
index.php:

```
include 'header.php';

if(!isset($_GET['page']) or !file_exists($_GET['page'] . '.php') {
    include_once 'home.php';
} else {
    include_once $_GET['page'] . '.php';
}

include 'footer.php';
```

here the code works good with /index.php?page=test
but with my rewrite url

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

here the code doesn't work with the url /page/test, the problem is he just include test.php my header and footer is not included, i don't know why...

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with your question, but your code has serious security issues, you need to verify that `page` doesn't have a backslash or `..` inside of it

Comment: yea yea, i have do it, i dont have copy past my code, he have more detail, have just write it here to show an exemple

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a absolute/relative URL issue. WHen you go to the `/page/XXXX` URL, you've changed your relative URL base from `/` to `/page/`, so you need to change all your links so that they're absolute URLs or include a relative URL base in the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/" />
```